# Why do I have two borders around my content?

Tags: html, css, border

Why does my content have two red borders around them?

Here is an image of what the code looks like next to the result:

[image: Here is an image of what the code looks like next to the result]

Here is the code that I am using to make the content.

```css
  * {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  margin: 25px auto;
  width: 1140px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

#first {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  width: 300px;
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#notes-example {
  border: 1px #ff0000 solid;
  padding: 25px;
```

```html
<div id="notes-example">
  <ol id="notes-example">
    <h2 id="first">Example of how the notes will be laid out</h2><br>
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis totam, blanditiis quibusdam suscipit in, omnis quo consequuntur porro sint reprehenderit necessitatibus ipsam? Beatae ea numquam, ducimus nostrum est id officiis.</li><br>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores optio eos sequi, laudantium culpa quaerat perspiciatis laborum sed eaque reiciendis quam alias in corporis, odio omnis temporibus hic aliquid aliquam!</li><br>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi placeat blanditiis, animi sequi. Vel, fuga architecto repellendus incidunt provident sapiente vitae. Perspiciatis id nisi maxime, nemo alias quo? Rem, accusamus!</li><br>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam tenetur corrupti cupiditate delectus eos autem quae tempore inventore iusto aliquam hic optio magnam quibusdam labore obcaecati eius, fugit vel esse.</li><br>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam delectus eaque, placeat, labore illum commodi atque dignissimos beatae doloremque corrupti dolor accusantium. Inventore temporibus unde saepe aperiam, amet consequatur velit?</li><br>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Here is an updated video snipped of removing border property from #notes-example as suggested https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyCzV.jpg

Comment: You applied #notes-example at 2 place so

Comment: `<div id="notes-example"><ol id="notes-example">` because you've specified the same ID two times, which is not the right way.

Comment: @asobak your answer was the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call notes-example twice which is causing the border to be applied twice.

Either only call that once, or you can rename one of the divs to only apply the style without the border.

For you I think this is what you are after in the HTML code. Otherwise just add a new div ID name (i.e notes-example2) and put it within the CSS with padding in there but not the border.

```
<div>
<ol id="notes-example">
<h2 id="first">Example of how the notes will be laid out</h2><br>
<h3>Heading</h3> 
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis totam, blanditiis quibusdam suscipit in, omnis quo consequuntur porro sint reprehenderit necessitatibus ipsam? Beatae ea numquam, ducimus nostrum est id officiis.</li><br>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores optio eos sequi, laudantium culpa quaerat perspiciatis laborum sed eaque reiciendis quam alias in corporis, odio omnis temporibus hic aliquid aliquam!</li><br>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi placeat blanditiis, animi sequi. Vel, fuga architecto repellendus incidunt provident sapiente vitae. Perspiciatis id nisi maxime, nemo alias quo? Rem, accusamus!</li><br>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam tenetur corrupti cupiditate delectus eos autem quae tempore inventore iusto aliquam hic optio magnam quibusdam labore obcaecati eius, fugit vel esse.</li><br>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam delectus eaque, placeat, labore illum commodi atque dignissimos beatae doloremque corrupti dolor accusantium. Inventore temporibus unde saepe aperiam, amet consequatur velit?</li><br>
</ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this snippet. have remove the border and id from the div

```css
    * {
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
  }
  body {
   background-color:#0000ff;
   margin: 25px auto;
   width:1140px;
   height:400px;
   float:left;
   color:white;
  }
  #first {
   border:1px solid #ff0000;
   width:300px;
   color:red;
   background-color:black;
   padding:10px;
   margin:5px;
  }
  #notes-example {
   padding:25px;
border:1px solid #ff0000;}
```

```html
<div>
<ol id="notes-example">
<h2 id="first">Example of how the notes will be laid out</h2><br>
<h3>Heading</h3> 
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis totam, blanditiis quibusdam suscipit in, omnis quo consequuntur porro sint reprehenderit necessitatibus ipsam? Beatae ea numquam, ducimus nostrum est id officiis.</li><br>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores optio eos sequi, laudantium culpa quaerat perspiciatis laborum sed eaque reiciendis quam alias in corporis, odio omnis temporibus hic aliquid aliquam!</li><br>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi placeat blanditiis, animi sequi. Vel, fuga architecto repellendus incidunt provident sapiente vitae. Perspiciatis id nisi maxime, nemo alias quo? Rem, accusamus!</li><br>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam tenetur corrupti cupiditate delectus eos autem quae tempore inventore iusto aliquam hic optio magnam quibusdam labore obcaecati eius, fugit vel esse.</li><br>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam delectus eaque, placeat, labore illum commodi atque dignissimos beatae doloremque corrupti dolor accusantium. Inventore temporibus unde saepe aperiam, amet consequatur velit?</li><br>
</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: OP obviously wants one border specified around his border, not two.

Comment: in that case add a broder to this this #notes-example {padding:25px; border:1px solid #ff0000;}

Comment: You got your solution ?

Comment: I think it would be better if ID is specified in div, not ol, but it doesn't matter. :)

Comment: right that doesn't matter you can add it where ever you want. if all good please accept the answer :)

Comment: Removing padding:25px; border:1px solid #ff0000; from #notes-example results in there being no border at all. Here is a link to imgr video of trying removal of the border code https://imgur.com/qfzweDW

Comment: you cannot remove the border and padding you have to decide where you want to call #notes-example.

Comment: and i see if you need some space before border then add padding in body will leave space before your div.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED. I needed to rename one of my id's to something else as two of them were named id="notes-example"

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Does that mean to click the up arrow on the left of the posts?

Comment: There is a tick underneath the down arrow, click the tick that helped answer your question.

Comment: I used the same id while referring to a div and an <ol> element. Changing one of the two id’s has solved the issue so I chose sumit rana’s response as well as @maze90 response

Answer (score 0):

You have given id "notes-example" on 2 elements . "notes-example